# orderBy positive or negative depending on input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/F0QjUynRiVjqA7lMJxom?p=info) is what I currently have, what I would like to do is have two radio buttons, that (depending on which one you selected) will change orderBy so it's negative or positive. However, even after looking a lot, I can't figure out how to do this properly.

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="true">$$$ - $</input>
<input type="radio" ng-value="false">$ - $$$</input>
...
<div ng-repeat="products in items | filter:search |orderBy:'-price'">
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says:

> ```
> {{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}
> ```
>
> reverse
>   (optional)
>     boolean
>
> Reverse the order of the array.

So you need your radio buttons to set a boolean value in the model. And that's exactly what ng-model does:

```
<input type="radio" name="order" ng-value="true" ng-model="reverse">$$$ - $</input>
<input type="radio" name="order" ng-value="false" ng-model="reverse">$ - $$$</input>
...
<div ng-repeat="products in items | filter:search | orderBy:'price':reverse">
```